# Can I exit the airport for my 7 hour layover in Paris?

Tags: germany, europe, schengen-visas, france, connecting-flights

I've got a German student visa (Schengen), and I'm flying for the first time to Europe. On my way to Germany I have a 7 hour layover at Paris. Can I exit the airport and come back? Or can I only enter for the first time through Germany? My visa is a "D" type visa

Comment: as a side note, with a 7 hours layover, you'd most likely get there faster by train (even Berlin, pretty fast East, is only 8 hours from Gare de l'Est)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your flight to Paris departed from a non-Schengen country, you will pass through Schengen immigration when you land in Paris. After clearing immigration, you will be free to leave the airport if you wish. CDG is a long way from the city center; Orly is closer in.

With your German visa, you can enter the Schengen area through any Schengen country. Entry through France while on your way to Germany is perfectly OK.